# How to remove empty columns from homepage?

Tags: page-layout, site-column, layouts

I have added a three column layout to my homepage. How can I remove them? I can only see how to remove *contents*, but not the columns itself?

[image: Layout draft]

Comment: Have you tried changing your page layout away from the 3-column layout?

Comment: You can create your custom page layout with desired number of columns or you can modify that existing page layout by downloading from http://<servername>/_catalogs/masterpage edit it re upload it.

Comment: Is it a web part page or a wiki page?

Comment: It's a web part page. I added a screenshot to specify.

Answer (score 0):

Without Pubslishing feature active you can do the following:

Open up your Web Part Page in SharePoint Designer. In there you will find an HTML table similar to this one:

```
<table class="ms-core-tableNoSpace ms-webpartPage-root" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" colspan="3" valign="top" width="100%"> 
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:Header" ID="Header" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" height="100%"> 
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:LeftColumn" ID="LeftColumn" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate><... webpart 1 content...></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
        <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" height="100%"> 
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:MiddleColumn" ID="MiddleColumn" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate><... webpart 2 content...></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
        <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" height="100%"> 
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:RightColumn" ID="RightColumn" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate><... webpart 3 content...></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" colspan="3" valign="top" width="100%"> 
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:Footer" ID="Footer" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
    </tr>
    <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">if(typeof(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == "function") {MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();}</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
</table>
```

in your case, since you have filled some of the WebPartZones with content already, it will probably be much longer.

Up there you see the original 3-column layout with Header and Footer row.
To get rid of the Webpart zones, simply restructure the HTML to your liking. if you want to combine the 3 columns into one without loosing their webparts , you will have to copy the content of the <ZoneTemplate>-tag of each of the <td>-tags (aka 'columns') you want to remove into the <ZoneTemplate>-tag of the <td>-tag that you want to keep and then you delete the <td>-tags that you want to remove.

Since Header and Footer don't span multiple columns anymore you have to remove their *colspan*-attribute.

Here is how it might look like afterwards, with the 3 columns in the center combined into one:

```
<table class="ms-core-tableNoSpace ms-webpartPage-root" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" align="top" width="100%"> 
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:Header" ID="Header" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" height="100%"> 
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:LeftColumn" ID="LeftColumn" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate><... webpart 1 content...><... webpart 2 content...><... webpart 3 content...></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" width="100%"> 
        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:Footer" ID="Footer" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
    </tr>
    <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">if(typeof(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == "function") {MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();}</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
</table>
```

Please note that this procedure will customize the page so that it is no longer based on the site definition.